# Retrofit - app crashes when I call intent to open new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, retrofit

I am relatively new to android, and I just started playing with retrofit. Currently I am making a restaurant app. At first I was using ***volley*** to get the restaurant list from the server. I downloaded the restaurant info to local database and added it to my mapFragment and restaurantListFragment. Then I decided to start using ***retrofit*** instead of volley. I succeeded to do the same with Retrofit - display restaurants in my two fragments.

But now ***I have a weird problem that, I think, should not be related to retrofit - if I try to open an intent my app crashes***. I have a navdrawer that crashes when I try to open activity from it. Also I had an option to add a restaurant on longclick on map. Longclick would call an intent and open setRestaurantActivity. It also crashes.

This is what I get when I try to open a navdrawer activity.

```
02-06 11:45:31.862 18777-18777/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-06 11:45:31.862 18777-18777/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x5cc97b20)
02-06 11:45:31.862 7010-7080/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-Application: Application crash has been observed. 
02-06 11:45:31.862 7010-7080/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor W/BstCommandProcessor-Application: in sendHttpRequest, requestType is of CRASH_APP type but one of the requiredInfo is NULL, crashedApp = com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor.BstCrashedAppInfo@2e75f9cc
02-06 11:45:31.862 18777-18777/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18777 SIG: 9
02-06 11:45:31.862 18777-18777/? D/AndroidRuntime: procName from cmdline: com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant
02-06 11:45:31.862 18777-18777/? E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant
02-06 11:45:31.862 18777-18777/? D/AndroidRuntime: file written successfully with content: com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant StringBuffer : ;com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant
02-06 11:45:31.862 18777-18777/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant, PID: 18777
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value      com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant.model.Restaurant@2e7b673c
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1266)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:653)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1226)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:148)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1133)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:563)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1285)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1204)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2474)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3098)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 11:45:31.872 6820-12714/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant (pid 18777) has died.
02-06 11:45:31.872 6820-12714/system_process W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{2e93b954 u0 com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant/.navdraweractivities.MyProfileActivity t11}: app died, no saved state
02-06 11:45:31.872 6820-12714/system_process V/WindowManager: isVisibleLw false for win : Window{2e9a6c20 u0 com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant/com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant.navdraweractivities.MyProfileActivity}
02-06 11:45:31.872 6820-12714/system_process W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{2e7170c8 u0 com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant/.MainActivity t11}: app died, no saved state
02-06 11:45:31.872 6820-12714/system_process D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome activityName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome/com.uncube.launcher3.Launcher callingPackage:   bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
02-06 11:45:31.872 6820-7036/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{2e9a6c20 u0 com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant/com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant.navdraweractivities.MyProfileActivity}
02-06 11:45:31.872 6820-7008/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{2ea83b54 u0 com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant/com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant.MainActivity}
02-06 11:45:31.872 7023-7023/com.bluestacks.appguidance D/GuidanceScreen: event === app_launch
02-06 11:45:31.872 7023-7023/com.bluestacks.appguidance D/GuidanceScreen: hiding guidance
02-06 11:45:31.872 7023-7023/com.bluestacks.appguidance D/GuidanceScreen: hardKeyboard = 1
02-06 11:45:31.872 7023-7023/com.bluestacks.appguidance D/GuidanceScreen: controllerType === Keyboard
02-06 11:45:31.872 6820-12714/system_process D/ActivityManager: Showing guidance for pkgName: com.bluestacks.gamepophome
02-06 11:45:31.882 6810-6810/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
02-06 11:45:31.882 7023-7023/com.bluestacks.appguidance D/GuidanceScreen: appName: Torque Launcher, currentPkg: com.bluestacks.gamepophome, event: app_launch, controller: Keyboard
02-06 11:45:31.882 7023-7023/com.bluestacks.appguidance D/GuidanceScreen: appName: Torque Launcher
02-06 11:45:31.892 7010-19051/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: command: ping
02-06 11:45:31.892 7010-19051/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: response: {"result":"ok"}
02-06 11:45:31.892 7010-19052/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: command: getdefaultlauncher
02-06 11:45:31.892 7010-19052/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: response: {"defaultLauncher":"com.bluestacks.gamepophome","result":"ok"}
02-06 11:45:31.902 7010-19053/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: command: ping
02-06 11:45:31.902 7010-19053/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: response: {"result":"ok"}
02-06 11:45:31.902 7010-19055/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: command: ping
02-06 11:45:31.902 7010-19055/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: response: {"result":"ok"}
02-06 11:45:31.912 7010-19054/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: command: StopApp com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant
02-06 11:45:31.912 7010-19054/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-Application: in isSystemReady, isBootCompleted true External storage status: mounted  External storage dir :/storage/sdcard  isExternalStorageRemovable:true
```

This is how my navdrawer looks like (was not changed after I started using retrofitting), and worked before:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.nav_account) {
    // Handle the account action
    Intent accountIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyProfileActivity.class);
    startActivity(accountIntent);
} else if (id == R.id.nav_contacts) {
    Intent contactsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FavouriteRestaurantsListActivity.class);
    startActivity(contactsIntent);
} else if (id == R.id.nav_blocked) {
    Intent blockedIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BlockedRestaurantsListActivity.class);
    startActivity(blockedIntent);
} else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.logging_out)
            .setMessage(R.string.logout_yes_no)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    logoutUser();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null);

    AlertDialog alert = builder.show();
    TextView messageText = (TextView) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    if (messageText != null) {
    messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }
}

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
return true;
}
```

And this is a call to setRestaurantActivity called from my map fragment:

```
                mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng arg0) {

                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + String.valueOf(arg0.latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(arg0.longitude) + "&key=myKey ";

                    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONArray jObj = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("address_components");

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SetRestaurantActivity.class);

                                        for (int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++) {
                                            String componentName = new JSONObject(jObj.getString(i)).getJSONArray("types").getString(0);
                                            if (componentName.equals("postal_code") || componentName.equals("locality") || componentName.equals("street_number") || componentName.equals("route")
                                                    || componentName.equals("neighborhood") || componentName.equals("sublocality") || componentName.equals("administrative_area_level_2")
                                                    || componentName.equals("administrative_area_level_1") || componentName.equals("country")) {
                                                intent.putExtra(componentName, new JSONObject(jObj.getString(i)).getString("short_name"));
                                            }
                                        }

                                        intent.putExtra("latitude", arg0.latitude);
                                        intent.putExtra("longitude", arg0.longitude);

                                        startActivity(intent);

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            int x = 1;
                        }
                    });
                    queue.add(stringRequest);

                }
            });
```

My Restaurant model:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Restaurant {
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String userName;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("image")
    private String thumbnailUrl;
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    private String lat;
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    private String lon;
    @SerializedName("event_date")
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("event_time")
    private String time;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("created_datetime")
    private String createdDateTime;

public Restaurant() {
}

public Restaurant(String name, String thumbnailUrl, String date, String time, String lat, String lon) {
    this.userName = name;
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String name) {
    this.userName = name;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}

public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(String latitude) {
    this.lat = latitude;
}

public String getLon() {
    return lon;
}

public void setLon(String longitude) {
    this.lon = longitude;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getCreatedDateTime() {
    return createdDateTime;
}

public void setCreatedDateTime(String createdDateTime) {
    this.createdDateTime = createdDateTime;
}
}
```

onSavedInstanceState:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // save the tutorial page (or something else)
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TutPage", tutorialPage);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("tutUsed", tutorialUsed);
    // more additions possible
}
```

Edited Restaurant model - working version:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Restaurant implements Parcelable{
@SerializedName("user_id")
private String userId;
@SerializedName("name")
private String userName;
@SerializedName("message")
private String message;
@SerializedName("image")
private String thumbnailUrl;
@SerializedName("latitude")
private String lat;
@SerializedName("longitude")
private String lon;
@SerializedName("event_date")
private String date;
@SerializedName("event_time")
private String time;
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("created_datetime")
private String createdDateTime;

public Restaurant() {
}

public Restaurant(String name, String thumbnailUrl, String date, String time, String lat, String lon) {
    this.userName = name;
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
}

protected Restaurant(Parcel in) {
    userId = in.readString();
    userName = in.readString();
    message = in.readString();
    thumbnailUrl = in.readString();
    lat = in.readString();
    lon = in.readString();
    date = in.readString();
    time = in.readString();
    id = in.readString();
    createdDateTime = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<Restaurant> CREATOR = new Creator<Restaurant>() {
    @Override
    public Restaurant createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Restaurant(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Restaurant[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Restaurant[size];
    }
};

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String name) {
    this.userName = name;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}

public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(String latitude) {
    this.lat = latitude;
}

public String getLon() {
    return lon;
}

public void setLon(String longitude) {
    this.lon = longitude;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getCreatedDateTime() {
    return createdDateTime;
}

public void setCreatedDateTime(String createdDateTime) {
    this.createdDateTime = createdDateTime;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(userId);
    parcel.writeString(userName);
    parcel.writeString(message);
    parcel.writeString(thumbnailUrl);
    parcel.writeString(lat);
    parcel.writeString(lon);
    parcel.writeString(date);
    parcel.writeString(time);
    parcel.writeString(id);
    parcel.writeString(createdDateTime);
}
}
```

Comment: paste your model class

Comment: @Android jack - Rajesh Gosemath Here it is. As I said, I am a beginner in both android and retrofit, but this confuses me, because it seems this should not be related.

Comment: Can you show `onSavedInstanceState` of the activity that is being left? There is a problem while writing `Restaurant` object into a `Parcel`, obviously because `Restaurant` does not implement `Parcelable`. You may try to make `Restaurant` class implement `Parcelable` as a workaround. But the question is where from do you want to write `Restaurant` object into a `Bundle`.

Comment: @azizbekian here it is.

Comment: Have you tried making `Restaurant` implement `Parcelable`?

Comment: @azizbekian Thank you Aziz, it worked :). If you want to answer it and post the Restaurant activity I will accept your answer. Thanks again

Comment: @Kemo, you're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From line:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value      com.weekendcoder.kemo.restaurant.model.Restaurant@2e7b673c
```

one may deduct, that `Restaurant` object wants to be written into a parcel, but it can't happen, because `Restaurant` is not parcelable.

Making `Restaurant` class implement `Parcelable` interface would solve the issue.

Comment: I have added an edited version of Restaurant model to my question as well. This one works for me. If it is not properly written please let me know. Thanks again Aziz.

Comment: That's ok. The only point I want to mention is, that the order is important when writing and reading values. If you mess the order of writing in `writeToParcel` and reading from it - you'd run in runtime exception. The ordering you have now is right, but that doesn't match the order of declaration of the fields in the class, which is counterintuitive.